# Understanding where to put constraints validation for REST api service using Spring

Tags: spring, api, rest, software-design, business-logic

I'm working on a REST api for a model having the following entities:

[image]

A `Team` cannot exists if it has no relationships with a `Course` and a `Student`. At the beginning, I created an endpoint for the teams (`API/teams`) for the CRUD operations. Now I ended up moving all the CRUD operations for the teams under the following URLs:

`/API/courses/{courseId}/teams`

The same has been done for `Machine` that cannot exists without any relationships with a `Team` and `Student`, so any CRUD operation should be done to the following:

`/API/courses/{courseId}/teams/{teamId}/virtual-machines`

This makes sense to me, since every time I need to perform an operation on a `Machine` I have to verify the constraint for which the `Machine` is owned by a `Team` related to a `Course`. For this reason, If I continued to perform any operation on URLs like `/API/teams` I should have requested the course and team ids to verify those contraints in the request body.

Having said this, my `CourseController` invokes a `VirtualMachineService` for all the operations on the `Machine` entity. What it seems odd to me is that each signature of every method in the `VirtualMachineService` need to have the course and the team id to verify the above constraints. This caused to have lots of duplicated code in every method.

1. Are my design choices correct?

The `CourseController` only have to invoke the methods of `VirtualMachineService` and to validate the parameters coming from the requests body.

2. Should those constraints validation be done inside the controller or inside the service?

Comment: `I'm working on a REST api for a model having ...` May I ask why you want to create a REST API in particular? Is your goal just to expose your domain model remotely or is your goal to create a system that may last for decades to come and that should be able to evolve freely in future without breaking clients? The latter one should be the only reason why you chose REST, everything other is probably easier with other technologies (but does not deserve the term REST then)

Comment: In addition to that, domain objects usually do not map directly onto resources. As [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=26m31s) pointed out, there are 2 models, the interaction model through Web governed by HTTP and the domain model and the two are different. Resources adapt domain objects and enrich these with hypertext controls and further data that is external to your domain model. As such there is no 1:1 mapping between domain objects and resources

Comment: Last but not least the spelling of URIs does not matter in a REST architecture and should furthermore not make sense to clients. In order to allow a server to change its URI structure anytime it wants to clients should lookup URIs based on accompanying link relation names that express the purpose of that link, i.e. `edit-form` or `prev`, `next`, `first` or `last` are often quoted ones.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Configuration nor Model are entities. Entities are classes from the domain (real world representations related to project, if you will), not every class you use.

REST doesn't directly care about your entity model (meaning graph) but you should follow the guidelines for specifying REST endpoints which is

different endpoint for

`/courses/...` and `/teams/...` - don't mix these. Any constraints you would like to apply are applied at the backend and have nothing to do with endpoint definitions.

Validation guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator